mailto: broken on Google Chrome (Ubuntu 24.04)
New Update: It turns out its only my profile with the issue. If I create a new profile in the same Chrome, it gets the OS default (thunderbird). I'm at a loss on how to fix my profile. I don't see any setting that can account for this. I have a lot invested in many windows and tabs and don't want to start over.
Update: Also works on Chromium (same rev as Chrome), It's just Chrome that insists on Gmail.
I have mailto: configured for Thunderbird in the Ubuntu Settings, and its honored by Firefox and even Microsoft Edge. However, Google Chrome keeps sending me to Gmail. I'm running the latest stable Chrome Version 125 on Ubuntu 24.04.
I've seem older posting on how to configure mailto: from inside Chrome, but none of the preferences mentioned show up in the current Chrome.
Any help?

By any chance, did you install Thunderbird and Firefox and Edge as snap, but Chrome as a deb package?

Neither are snaps. Chrome as part of system install and lives in /opt, Thunderbird download from Mozilla .
